# Android app crashes when service started on boot?

Tags: android, service

I've got a service, `MyService`, that I am initiating in a small test application using a simple button, as follows (source for the entire MainActivity):

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                startService(intent);               
            }
        });
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine - the service is started, and the pebble receives the data it requires from my android application.

However, I'd like to have this service running in the background upon boot, and not simply when the app starts. The way of doing this, apparently, is to declare the boot permission in the manifest file, along with the service itself:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

...

<service android:name="com.example.testapp.MyService" android:exported="false"/>
```

As well as declaring a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class OnStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
     context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Assuming that this is the correct implementation for a service on boot, when I restart my Android device and give everything some time to load (and ensure that the Pebble is connected to my phone), when I try to fetch data from the Android device through Pebble (that is, essentially, interact with the `Service`), the test app crashes. I then go into Settings->Applications and find that while the process for my test app has crashed, the service is still running, though it doesn't behave as expected and is probably just dead.

I've got no idea why this may be the issue. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Relevant Logcat Output:

```
V/Zygote  ( 2572): Switching descriptor 33 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 2572): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
D/dalvikvm( 2572): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  736): Start proc com.example.testapp for broadcast com.example.testapp/.OnStartReceiver: pid=2572 uid=10144 gids={50144}
D/ActivityThread( 2572): handleBindApplication:com.example.testapp
D/ActivityThread( 2572): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread( 2572): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
I/System.out( 2572): service is started
D/AndroidRuntime( 2572): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2572): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dcce0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572): Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 2572
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.getpebble.action.app.RECEIVE_NACK flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.testapp.MyService$1$2@4187ce88
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=60; index=-1
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at com.example.testapp.MyService$1$2.receiveNack(MyService.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at com.getpebble.android.kit.PebbleKit$PebbleNackReceiver.onReceive(PebbleKit.java:627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:775)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2572):    ... 9 more
I/Process ( 2572): Sending signal. PID: 2572 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  736): Process com.example.testapp (pid 2572) has died.
```

Comment: You need to provide logcat output and code.  This sounds like it is the test app which has the problem, not the service.

Comment: I'll update the original post now with code. However, I don't seem to get any logcat output in ADT/eclipse when my app crashes after a reboot of my Android device.

Comment: You may have to use adb logcat at the command line.  Eclipse will filter your logcat output to only the app you're running with it.  If something is crashing, it will show up with stack trace and details in the logcat.

Comment: I've added the full source for `MainActivity`. This file doesn't change whether I've got the `OnStartReceiver` in the program or not. If there's any other code that seems missing, please let me know.

Comment: The app code looks fine at first glance, but you really need the logcat output for the test app to see why it is crashing.

Comment: Got it. I'm working on getting the logcat output. It'll take a few minutes, however, as this is my first time using logcat from cmd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57426/discussion-between-holyhades666-and-larry-schiefer).

Answer (score 0):

As per your log the bug must be at

> MyService.java:184

you are reading element -1 of the array

if you post the source for MyService.java it should be easy to spot the problem